# Console notices relating to dpi CSS usage when using a tweet button

Tags: javascript, css, twitter

I'm using the default tweet button like this:

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/share">Tweet</a>
<script>
window.twttr=(function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],t=window.twttr||{};if(d.getElementById(id))return;js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);t._e=[];t.ready=function(f){t._e.push(f);};return t;}(document,"script","twitter-wjs"));
</script>
```

When I visit the console after page load, I get the following message appear:

> Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch,
>   not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi'
>   of a screen. In media query expression:
>   (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min-resolution: 144dpi)

As an example, go to the following page and visit the console. You'll see multiple instances of that same message.

How can this be resolved?

Ref: https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug from [Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336276)

To fix it you need to override the dpi with ddpx like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gMRv9/)

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) { 

  /* Retina-specific stuff here */
```

But since you're using the twitter code you might have to write your own custom @media to override it...